# longitude and latitude values are both 0.000000 , why?

Tags: ios, core-location

i use core location to get the longitude and latitude value of my current position and i have displayed it into a label, so for my case it's always 0.000000 for both longitude and latitude, is it because i work on the simulator ??

```
    //longitude and latitude
    // locationManager update as location
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self; 
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];

    // Configure the new event with information from the location
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude]; 
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];
```

Comment: Are you in a boat off the coast of Ghana?

Answer (score 3):

Just initialization the location manager doesn't fetch you values.

you have to write this

```
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

then you have to override a callback method

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
     didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *) newLocation
    fromLocation: (CLLocation *) oldLocation {


    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
     NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.latitude]; 
         NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.longitude];  
    [self.locationManager release];
}
```

Hope that helps!

- Shuanak

Comment: Hi, that's didn't help me, the same values are shown in the labels :((

Answer (score 0):

No. CoreLocation on the iPhone simulator is fixed at 37.3317 North, 122.0307 West (Apple HQ).

Try moving your locationManager code away from your code with the label. Put the location manager code in the viewDidLoad or something and then put this code

```
CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];

// Configure the new event with information from the location
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude]; 
NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];
```

in a function that you call from a button. CoreLocation needs time to get itself going. This is true on the device for sure, but perhaps it is also true on the simulator.